# Присоединительные члены предложения и двоеточие при перечислении

Tags: пунктуация

> Самые скороспелые грибы, например берёзовики и сыроежки, достигают
> полного развития в три дня. (Аксаков)

Возникла проблема: не могу понять, где следует ставить двоеточие (при перечислении), а где нужно обособлять запятыми с вводным словом (при присоединительных членах).

Может, возможен и такой вариант?

*Самые скороспелые грибы, например: берёзовики и сыроежки — достигают полного развития в три дня.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А у меня на этот вопрос **другой (альтернативный) ответ.**

1. В данном случае важно то, что два однородных члена **связаны одиночным союзом И,** поэтому их можно рассматривать **как единую конструкцию** со значением уточнения. Вводное слово в этом случае получает статус **присоединительного союза** и входит в уточняющий оборот:

(1) *Самые скороспелые грибы, **например берёзовики и сыроежки**, достигают полного развития в три дня.*

2. А теперь **уберем союз И**, а также добавим еще один член предложения, чтобы получился полноценный однородный ряд **с перечислением** (хотя можно и не добавлять):

(2) *Самые скороспелые грибы, например:  **берёзовики,  сыроежки,  маслята** – достигают полного развития в три дня.*

Теперь возможен только  **классический способ оформления однородного ряда по всем правилам:**  вводное слово, двоеточие перед однородным рядом и тире, замыкающее ряд.

3. Двоеточие обозначает **предупредительную паузу** перед перечислением. Как мы видим, **интонация** вариантов совершенно разная.

Comment: Да, у меня тоже была такая мысль, и, если честно, этот ответ, как по мне, выглядит более правдоподобно. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо и вам! Мне очень дороги ваши отзывы!.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Возникла проблема: не могу понять, где следует ставить двоеточие
  (при перечислении), а где — тире (при присоединительных членах).
```

А кто Вам сказал, что их непременно следует ставить? Если б было без вводного слова, тире и двоеточие были бы возможны, по крайней мере не были бы ошибкой:

*Самые скороспелые грибы: берёзовики и сыроежки - достигают полного развития в три дня.*

Тогда бы Вы сказали:"После обобщающего слова двоеточие, после однородных членов тире, так как предложение продолжается".

Но у Вас предложение с присоединительными приложениями, которые начинаются с вводного слова, в таком случае вся группа обосабливается с помощью запятых и запятая после вводного слова не ставится, чтобы указать, что оно относится именно к приложениям, а не к подлежащему:

*Самые скороспелые грибы, например берёзовики и сыроежки, достигают полного развития в три дня (Аксаков)*

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. «А кто Вам сказал, что их непременно следует ставить?» — Упс, ошибся: имел в виду, что не понял, где ставится двоеточие, а где обособляется с вводным словом. «Но у Вас предложение с присоединительными приложениями, которые начинаются с вводного слова, в таком случае вся группа обосабливается с помощью запятых и запятая после вводного слова не ставится…» — Значит, нужно обособлять приложение с вводным словом? Можно ли найти это правило где-то?

Comment: Вот, пожалуйста, в справочнике Розенталя: 4. Если вводное слово (сочетание) стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения), то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно не отделяется. _Для определения расстояния можно смотреть даже на небольшой предмет, **например бугорок или кочку**._ [Запятой после "например" нет.] http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=32